# What is the Policy for Integrating with Official Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I'm looking at some of the Apple related documentation tags, and I'm wondering how to works with citations, copying text and code samples from Apple's website. (Apple is my example here, but consider your favorite technology from your favorite company.)

Apple's documentation for iOS, macOS, and friends is really good. I think there's a place for them here, because we get a few benefits with documentation:

- StackOverflow users can edit documentation that Apple might not update for several years
- We can also add examples that speak to common questions that Apple hasn't addressed.
- links won't die or break as often as they do on third party websites.

That being said, what's the network's expectation for citation, plagiarism, and copying? Is it okay to copy a code sample and cite? With a link or without?

Comment: Microsoft is working on something similar, except [in the opposite direction](https://docs.microsoft.com/teamblog/stackoverflow-documentation-for-microsoft-developers).

Comment: Hey, that's pretty cool!